# Set NSWindow Size programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, window, size, nswindow

How can I set the window size programmatically? I have a  window in IB and I want to set the size of it in my code to make it larger.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `-setFrame:display:animate:` for maximum control:

```
NSRect frame = [window frame];
frame.size = theSizeYouWant;
[window setFrame: frame display: YES animate: whetherYouWantAnimation];
```

Note that window coordinates are flipped from what you might be used to. The origin point of a rectangle is at its bottom left in Quartz/Cocoa on OS X. To ensure the origin point remains the same:

```
NSRect frame = [window frame];
frame.origin.y -= frame.size.height; // remove the old height
frame.origin.y += theSizeYouWant.height; // add the new height
frame.size = theSizeYouWant;
// continue as before
```

Comment: @Leo's answer has a point, or at least I saw the same thing - the +/- should be reversed.

Comment: i have try this code but still my window moving downwards. any solution to stop moving window.

Comment: Works perfectly for me. I wanted to programmatically resize a window controller that was being presented as a sheet view. Thanks!

Comment: please note that immediate size change in viewDidAppear() would not work, put timer or something else...

Answer (score 12):

It is actually seems that +/- need to be reversed to keep window from moving on the screen:

```
NSRect frame = [window frame];
frame.origin.y += frame.size.height; // origin.y is top Y coordinate now
frame.origin.y -= theSizeYouWant.height; // new Y coordinate for the origin
frame.size = theSizeYouWant;
```

Comment: Or better still: frame.origin.y += (frame.size.height - theSizeYouWant.height);

Answer (score 8):

Swift version

```
var frame = self.view.window?.frame
frame?.size = NSSize(width: 400, height:200)
self.view.window?.setFrame(frame!, display: true)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`setFrame:display:animate:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/setFrame%3adisplay%3aanimate%3a)

```
[window setFrame:NSMakeRect(0.f, 0.f, 200.f, 200.f) display:YES animate:YES];
```

Comment: Don't know what NSMakeFrame is. I use NSMakeRect.

Answer (score 4):

Usually I want to resize the window based on the **size of the content** (not including the title bar):

```swift
var rect = window.contentRect(forFrameRect: window.frame)
rect.size = myKnownContentSize
let frame = window.frameRect(forContentRect: rect)
window.setFrame(frame, display: true, animate: true)
```

Comment: How are you deriving `myKnownContentSize`?

Comment: `myKnownContentSize` is just whatever size I want for my window contents. This code snippet then makes the window itself a corresponding size that accommodates the title bar (or other future OS additions).

Answer (score 0):

my two cents for swift 4.x 7 OSX:

a) do not call on viewDidLoad
b) go on main queue...
b) wait some time... so for example use:

```
private final func setSize(){
    if let w = self.view.window{
        var frame = w.frame
        frame.size = NSSize(width: 400, height: 800)
        w.setFrame(frame, display: true, animate: true)

    }
}
```