# How to set NSWindow width and height programmatically in storyboard cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, storyboard

I have set the `minimum window width` and `minimum height` from the interface property, but when I run the app it shows a small width instead. And after applying `stretch` to the window it resizes according to the given parameter in property of storyboard window.

I have tried this:

```
[theWindow setMaxSize:windowMaxSize];
[theWindow setMinSize:windowMinSize];
```

But it works in XIB. And I have a storyboard.

So I want to set `width` and `height` programmatically.

Comment: see this question may be it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438224/set-nswindow-size-programmatically